# mongodb replicaset of one autoscaling

Tags: mongodb, jelastic, mongodb-replica-set

Will it autoscale database ram/disk and instances? Specifically will it autoscale instances and work if I create a simple replicaset of one node for the oplog alone? It doesn't support creating replicaset of 1 in interface, so I worry that it will not detect replicaset to add nodes to.

It just scaled down to 3 droplets, which amounts to just 15 usd, much better than where it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I've added autoscaling rule with the corresponding rule for scaling down (I used disk i/o metric). It just shut down the other two nodes, which is fair enough since thats why you start with 3 :D (in case one, or two goes down). The horizontal scaling rule settings are opened in a list thats opend with settings button on environment entry in the list on dashboard.